# GTD Android app

Tags: android, time-management

I'm looking for a GTD (Getting Things Done) app for Android that has the following features:

- Lightweight and easy-to-use (no need for feature creep)
- Possibility to sync the tasks between devices and/or access the tasks from a web browser (this is mostly to ensure that tasks are backed up continuously)
- Possibility to schedule the tasks in a calendar, where tasks past the due date are automatically advanced to today's date
- Widget, showing both "to do" tasks and "past due date" tasks
- Does not require a monthly fee (it's ok if the app is non-free, though)

This is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16898/getting-things-done-gtd-web-or-cross-platform-app) since the requirements are less strict.

So far I've tested **[Chaos Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tarasovmobile.gtd)** which fulfills all these points; the only doubt I have is that it's made by a small company, so there's always the risk the project might be abandoned at some point.

I've also tested **[Trello](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trello)** but wasn't satisfied by it because of its complexity and its lack of a calendar.

Comment: Dmitriy from Chaos Control here. We're a small company, but no worries; we're here for long. I hope you'd like the future updates we're working on right now.

Comment: @DmitriyTarasov Great to know :) I'll probably buy the Premium version then. Thanks for your feedback, and keep up the good work.

Comment: I like taskpad to prioritize tasks. I like checklist for quick tasks, device syncing and it's widget. I just purchased goal meter. I'm impressed with it's artwork but disappointed with widget and rest features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the most promising app I've found for what I need is **[Toodledo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwlm.mytoodle&hl=en)**. It fulfills all the requirements above, plus it is powerful and enough well-known to have a lot of support and 3rd-party plugins.

But if you're looking for something more lightweight, I'd suggest give **Chaos Control** a try.