# Simple GTD app with priority matrix and home widget

Tags: android, web-apps, time-management, todo

(This is not the duplicate of [GTD Android App](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28263/gtd-android-app) and [GTD web or cross-platform app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16898/getting-things-done-gtd-web-or-cross-platform-app).)

I'm looking for a GTD app with following features:

- Home widget which accepts **single tap** activity to

  - mark a task: done, deleted, do it later
  - add/edit task
- Let me maintain long check lists, nested lists, grouped lists etc.
- I can mark some tasks from the checklist to do it today
- Today list should be just the reference list of tasks from other checklist
- Multi platform (Android, and web)
- Supports priority matrix (recommended but optional)
- One time purchase is fine

#### Why not checklist app?

It matches most of the features I'm looking for. But

- Don't have priority matrix (can be ignored)
- Need to copy paste tasks from other lists to today list

#### Why not Taskpad?

Really good, specially adding task from widget. But

- Difficult to maintain long lists
- Don't support nested lists
- Need 3 taps to mark a task done
- No separate list for today

#### Why not Goal Meter? (I've tried its premium version)

It's cool art make me relaxed. But

- Need 3 taps to mark a task done
- Beautiful arts reduce number of tasks to display on the home widget
- Multiple taps to add a task

Comment: People who are using checklist.com web, you can use [following](https://gist.github.com/amitguptagwl/336a37701346d0dce1c3e325a77fa594) snippet to make nested lists collapsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Toodledo**

I believe this application can address all the feature I'm looking for in following ways.

- For today virtual list

  - Either I can change the status of a task to "Next Action", or star a task, or change it's priority to "Top", or tag it as "today", or create a context "today" ... so many ways.
  - Then configure widget to show hotlist or a list satisfying any criteria given in above point.
- For priority matrix, I'm tagging tasks as either urgent or important or both.
- Syncing has an issue. But it has cross platform support.
- It let me made long check lists. Nested checklists is a paid feature but I can create multiple folders in this case.